# nginx rtmp with no subscribers die after a minute

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I have a simple nginx-rtmp running with the following application:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;

        application tv {
            # enable live streaming
            live on;

            allow publish all;
            allow play all;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that when I start streaming from a publisher, if I don't connect a subscriber within the minute, it will "die" and then I can't connect anymore until I restart the stream and connect a subscriber fast enough.
Is there any directive that I can use to avoid this? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How many workers do you have?

Comment: @Federico Sierra : `worker_processes auto;`

Comment: May be a problem with multiple workers, try with `rtmp_auto_push on` https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#multi-worker-live-streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either setting the `worker_processes 1` or `rtmp_auto_push on` works.

Thanks @Federico Sierra for the comment.